# When using this formula to draw a circle on a sphere, why is the circle missing a part?

Tags: geometry

[image]

When using this formula to draw a circle on a sphere, why is the circle missing a part?

$\beta=\arctan(k\sin\alpha)-\arcsin\cfrac{d\sqrt{1+k^2}}{\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2\alpha}} 
$

$k=1$

$d=-0.9$

$β$ is latitude,

$α$ is longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a range of values of $\alpha$ for which expression under $arcsin$ will be less than $-1$.

Comment: Are you saying that some of the data is not in the range of arcsin?  So how do I make the drawn circle no longer have only a part?

Comment: >>"some of the data is not in the range of arcsin?" Exactly.

The most simple way to fix it is to choose $k$ and $d$ such that $|d| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^{2}}}$

Comment: How did you get this formula?

Comment: You need an expression under $arcsin$ to be in $[-1; 1]$ for every $\alpha$. That is numerator of the corresponding fraction should be always not greater than denominator by absolute value. We can see, that only denominator depends on $\alpha$. And, what is more, denominator is always not greater than $\sqrt{1+k^{2}}$. The most extreme case is when $\alpha = 0$, then the whole expression is equal to $d\sqrt{1+k^{2}}$ and still must be in [-1; 1] which yields the condition from my previous comment.

Comment: When $ \sqrt {1 +  ^ 2} ≤1$ , what method can be used to make the circle no longer a part?

Comment: Please, note that the correct inequality is $-1 \leq d\sqrt{1+k^2} \leq 1$. 
If you choose such $k$ and $d$, then you should be able to draw full circle with the same method, which you used initially. Did you try it? Which $k$ and $d$ have you chosen?

Comment: Of course, if it is consistent with the conditions, the entire circle can be drawn.  But if it is not consistent with the conditions, how can I draw the entire circle?

Comment: You have no other degrees of freedom in the formula besides $k$ and $d$. So you have only two choices: you can either change $k$ and $d$ or you can choose some entirely different formula.
If your question is about which other formulas do exist, then I do not have an immediate answer.